# Cannot see syntax issue in JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

What's wrong with this:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', 
     'hitCallBack': function() {
    ga('set', 'dimension12', some_var);
    };
```

Comment: And you're omitting the error message to make the question even less useful?

Comment: "I'll delete this question shortly" - that's not how the SE sites were intended to work. If you want to ask a question and then delete it afterwards, maybe Reddit would be a better approach (and even there it is annoying). I wonder whether using an IDE would assist here - it'll mark the syntax error even without running the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The opening `ga(` isn't closed anywhere...

Comment: No worries - I've been there before, too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
ga('send', 'pageview', 
     'hitCallBack': function() {
    ga('set', 'dimension12', some_var);
    )};
```

Notice the ")" on the last line. You should close the first "ga("

Comment: Then please explain to me why
_The opening ga( isn't closed anywhere..._
is the accepted answer

Comment: the `'hitCallBack': function() ` is like part of an object, but the object literal is missing. the accepted answer is not complete, anyhow ...

Answer (score 0):

Bracket at the end needed

```
ga('send', 'pageview', 
 'hitCallBack': function() {
  ga('set', 'dimension12', some_var);
});
```